# building own template Rmd - how to deal with $for$ loop properly

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have started my own template in Rmd. I want to create custom variables in `yaml` chunk in .Rmd file and then execute them in my own html `template`. The problem is that I want to use for loop `$for$` to build several links and each should have unique name.
For example when I create in my html `template` part

```
...
$if(appendix)$
<h3>Appendices</h3>
$for(appendix.file)$
<a href = "$appendix.link$">$appendix.name$</a>
$endfor$
$endif$
...
```

then in `yaml` part in my `.Rmd` file

```
---
appendix:
    name: [nameForFile1, nameForFile2]
    link: [file1.html, file2.html]
---
```

what I want to get in my final `html` file after rendering `.Rmd` is

```
<a href = "file1.html">nameForFile1</a>
<a href = "file2.html">nameForFile2</a>
```

But instead, this solution gives me

```
<a href = "file1.html">nameForFile1</a>
<a href = "file1.html">nameForFile2</a>
```

Obviously I understand why it happens. Does anybody know any workaround to solve this issue?

PS: I am trying to create general solution, therefore it would be great if it gives me a possibility to include numerous links.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned out it's not so difficult. Just change `yaml` file:

```
appendix: 
- name: "nameForFile1"
  link: file1.html
- name: "nameForFile2"
  link: file2.html
```

And `html` file:

```
...
$if(appendix)$
<h3>Appendices</h3>
$for(appendix)$
<a href = "$appendix.link$">$appendix.name$</a>
$endfor$
$endif$
...
```

You can find more related stuff [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html)